# OSError: Incorrect Parameter in _pswindows.py

Tags: python

I am currently working on a University Project. That's why I am not sure if I can post the code of the project, so I won't (It is pretty huge anyways).

Well, so I spent quite some time installing all the modules to get the program to run. This was a pain at first but with Anaconda I finally got all the modules installed.

Now I get this Error. I am not sure what it means. I looked at line 928 of _pswindows.py but it didn't help me.
I know this project was originally programmed on Linux starting about 2-3 years ago and I am using Windows 10 and Spyder, so maybe there lies the problem? Googling the Error didn't help either...

How could I fix this?

> File "ui-test.py", line 20, in 
>       web_ui_thread = WebUIThread(config_fln, user_config_fln, ui_par, debug=True)
>
> File "C:\Users\Flitschi\Documents\TU\BA\WebUI\Sprechhilfe-Python-ui\bionic_voice\webui\server.py", line 125, in **init**
>       p.nice(10)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil__init__.py", line 711, in nice
>       self._proc.nice_set(value)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil_pswindows.py", line 635, in wrapper
>       return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil_pswindows.py", line 928, in nice_set
>       return cext.proc_priority_set(self.pid, value)
>
> OSError: [WinError 87] Falscher Parameter

Comment: What is the line in your source code that is giving the error?

Comment: looks like a permissions problem. Can you run the code as administator?

Comment: you cannot post your code, but you can reproduce the issue and create a [mcve] probably...

Comment: @AaronGarton Not sure too be honest. I do not understand the whole code yet unfortunately. I included the whole Output of the Console maybe that helps.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried running Spyder as administrator. Still the same Error.

Comment: @FLITSCHI could you post the first line in the `runfile` method please? Or at least say what it's doing

Comment: @AaronGarton I just ran the file in the cmd promt and I believe this is the line casuing the error. web_ui_thread = WebUIThread(config_fln, user_config_fln, ui_par, debug=True)